# Error Correction with Python without chunking

Tags: python, error-correction

I was trying to achieve error correction for a (byte-) string with Reed Solomon, before sending it to a receiver. I used the following [library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reedsolo) for error correction and the following MWE:

```
from reedsolo import RSCodec

with open("imageToSend.png", "rb") as pic:
  picContent = pic.read()

correctionLength = int((len(picContent)/100)*20)
rs = RSCodec(correctionLength)

rs.encode(picContent)
```

As this doesn't work for my use case (deletion of whole 255 byte blocks are not recoverable), I am looking for a new approach. I want to do the following:

```
with open("imageToSend.png", "rb") as pic:
  picContent = pic.read()

# Create error correcting code of picContent and append it to the message (without chunking the message)

# Randomly delete 20% of the message

# Correct errors and restore original message
```

Performance (speed) is not an issue!

Comment: I don't think this is useful approach. This is not a separate question, I still have to read all the bunch of previous question comments. But if you totally remove the link to old question (at least, completely stop referring to it), and fix question accordingly, it may become useful.

Comment: Thanks for that- will be done in a few minutes :)